# table.Columns(1).Delete working only in debug mode, but not in production

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using a VBA script **in MS Word** to copy some rows from a table in one document to another table in another document. However, the original table has some extra columns that I would like to remove.

After copying all columns in place, I would like to delete all the extra columns. Therefore I do:

```
WhileAnd targetTable.Columns.Count > 4
    targetTable.Columns.Last.Delete
Wend
```

If I try this in debug mode, this works like a charm. No issue whatsover.

However when running without breakpoints, the columns are not deleted and this ends in an endless loop.

### My debug

In an effort to debug it, I added some Debug.Print statements. I also added a maximum iteration counter to avoid any endless loop. Finally, I tried to add a pause after deleting each column to avoid any "race condition".

```
i = 0
While i < 5 And targetTable.Columns.Count > 4
    Debug.Print "Iteration " & i
    Debug.Print "Service table has " & targetTable.Columns.Count & " columns"
    Debug.Print "Deleting a column"
    
    targetTable.Columns.Last.Delete
    
    Debug.Print "waiting few seconds"
    
    Wait 3
    
    Debug.Print "Now service table has " & targetTable.Columns.Count & " columns"
    Debug.Print "-----------------"
    i = i + 1 ' Emergency stop
Wend

Function Wait(ByVal Seconds As Single)
    Dim CurrentTimer As Variant
    CurrentTimer = Timer
    Do While Timer < CurrentTimer + Seconds
    Loop
End Function
```

This is the console output when there aren't any breakpoints

```
Iteration 0
Service table has 6 columns
Deleting a column
waiting few seconds
Now service table has 6 columns
-----------------
Iteration 1
Service table has 6 columns
Deleting a column
waiting few seconds
Now service table has 6 columns
-----------------
Iteration 2
Service table has 6 columns
Deleting a column
waiting few seconds
Now service table has 6 columns
-----------------
Iteration 3
Service table has 6 columns
Deleting a column
waiting few seconds
Now service table has 6 columns
-----------------
Iteration 4
Service table has 6 columns
Deleting a column
waiting few seconds
Now service table has 6 columns
-----------------
```

As you can see the number of columns never change.

However, if I debug it adding a breakpoint inside the while loop, the output is the following:

```
Iteration 0
Service table has 6 columns
Deleting a column
waiting few seconds
Now service table has 5 columns
-----------------
Iteration 1
Service table has 5 columns
Deleting a column
waiting few seconds
Now service table has 4 columns
-----------------
```

I also tried to change this into a For loop as

```
For i = targetTable.Columns.Count To 5 Step -1
    Debug.Print "Service table has " & targetTable.Columns.Count & " columns"
    targetTable.Columns.Last.Delete
    Wait 5
    Debug.Print "Now service table has " & targetTable.Columns.Count & " columns"
    Debug.Print "-----------------"
Next i
```

but the problem persisted.

Why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you happen to have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere before the code that deletes the columns (eg if 'in production' the procedure that does the deleting is called from another procedure that might have 'On Error Resume Next` whereas when you run 'in debug' you are running the procedure that does the deleting directly)? This combined with either a Table with merged cells or document protection could cause the problem?

Comment: Deleting activates Worksheet_Change, try disabling events. I tested the code and it works without Wait, so the problem is in side actions...

Comment: @JohnM no, I don't have any `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ Can you please suggest me how to try running this disabling events? PS: remember that we are in Word, not Excel. Is there a `Worksheet_Change` here as well? Are there `worksheets` at all in Word?

Comment: If you have also suggestions on how to debug and pinpoint the issue I will try that and update the question. Thank you very much

Comment: @Luca You're right, the test was done in excel, I didn't notice the tag...

Comment: Random suggestion that has no right to be right: try putting `DoEvents` inbetween the `Do` and `Loop` lines in your `Wait` function (otherwise `Wait` is just locking Word up and not giving it 'time to think')

Comment: @JohnM IT WORKED! You are a genius :) It was indeed a sort-of race condition, but my `Wait` function wasn't properly working. Would you like to write this as an answer?

Comment: I will ... but you have to wonder WHY it worked?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random suggestion that has no right to be right (but turns out it is):

Put `DoEvents` in-between the `Do` and `Loop` lines in your `Wait` function (otherwise `Wait` is just locking Word up and not giving it 'time to think')

Comment: This Wait function which is in the question's code, is a user defined function, which is not the same as `Wait` method of Excel. This function not block Word but runs in a loop until a defined time reached. DoEvents passes control to the OS.

Comment: @Blackcat the question relates to Word not Excel ... the answer is already confirmed as working (see comments below the question)

Comment: Exactly. And the original code run for me without any problem.

Comment: To improve on this answer, I found to solve the issue is enough to add DoEvents inside the `while` or `for` loop after deleting the column. This passes control over to word that can "take his time" to delete the column. I'm not sure why this is required for this specific action, but this solved the problem